# Chaining dependent observables

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, reactivex

I need to create dependent API calls where the second one needs a value returned by the first one. First thing that comes to mind is using flatMap

```
ApiManager.shared
    .createReport(report: report)
    .flatMap { (report) -> Observable<Report> in
        return ApiManager.shared.createReportStep(reportID: report.ID)
    }
```

`createReport` returns `Observable<Report>` where after successfull call returns updated `Report` model(with ID), after that I need to call API to create report step, where `report.ID` is needed.

Everything looks and works fine with that code, but the problem comes when I need to do something after each of these steps(`createReport` and `createReportStep`). I placed code in `onNext` block, but it is called only once, after both of the steps are completed.

Is there a way to receive onNext signal after both steps? I could use something like this:

```
ApiManager.shared
      .createReport(report: report)
      .concat(ApiManager.shared.createReportStep(reportID: report.ID))
```

Which would emmit two signals like I want, but then again where do I get updated `report.ID` from to pass to `createReportStep`?

Comment: Please help me understand your problem better. After creating a `Report`, you wish to create a `ReportStep` which requires the report ID generated after creating a report. The next thing you want to do is to have access to both the `Report` and the `ReportStep` objects that were just created. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind the time component and only need to have access to both `report` and what is returned by `createReportStep(reportID:)`, you could go with creating a tuple in `flatMap`'s block

```
ApiManager.shared
    .createReport(report: report)
    .flatMap { (report) -> Observable<Report> in
        return ApiManager.shared.createReportStep(reportID: report.ID)
            .map { (report, $0) }
    }
```

The resulting observable would contain both results in a tuple.

---

If the time component is important, you could do the following

```
let report = ApiManager.shared
  .createReport(report: report)
  .share()

let reportStep = report.map { $0.ID }.flatMap(ApiManager.shared.createReportStep)

Observable.concat([report, reportStep])
```

Here, the important bit is the `share` call. It will ensure `createReport` performs its work only once, but you would have two next events as requested.

Comment: I would guess that the time component is indeed important, assuming that Report IDs are unknown until the models are successfully created on the database. But that is merely a guess. :) lazyNeighbour would know his use case better than me.